# How to remove all the null elements inside a generic list in one go?

Tags: c#, list, null, element

Is there a default method defined in .Net for C# to remove all the elements within a list which are `null`?

```
List<EmailParameterClass> parameterList = new List<EmailParameterClass>{param1, param2, param3...};
```

Let's say some of the parameters are `null`; I cannot know in advance and I want to remove them from my list so that it only contains parameters which are not null.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

You'll probably want the following.

```
List<EmailParameterClass> parameterList = new List<EmailParameterClass>{param1, param2, param3...};
parameterList.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
```

Comment: Yep, this is the same as my answer but using the newer C#3 lambda syntax.

Comment: @Mark: I saw the posted seconds and man it was close (32, 33, and 34). ;)

Comment: Yeah... well your answer works even in older versions so +1! So there, ha! ;Þ

Comment: I would add the .Cast<T>() as in .Cast<EmailParameterClass>() at the end after the cleanup, this would change the type of the List<EmailParameterClass?> to List<EmailParameterClass>

Comment: The lambda could be made nicer using pattern matching in modern C# versions: `item => item is null`

Answer (score 61):

I do not know of any in-built method, but you could just use linq:

```
parameterList = parameterList.Where(x => x != null).ToList();
```

Comment: This should be avoided if `parameterList` is already a List, as it will unnecessarily create a new copy.  In that case use the `RemoveAll` method as others suggest.

Comment: This is probably the best option if the collection is an `Array`.

Comment: In C# 9, you can simplify the expression to `x => x is not null` for a bit of improved readability.

Answer (score 29):

The RemoveAll method should do the trick:

```
parameterList.RemoveAll(delegate (object o) { return o == null; });
```

Comment: Why not use the lambda?

Comment: This is a four year old answer. At the time C# 3 was relatively new, and I was still using C# 2 day-to-day. The lambda syntax is now the way to go; however, this is still a working answer, so I've left it here for anyone unable to use the newer syntax (for whatever reason).

Comment: I wasn't aware that the lambda syntax came later. Thank you for your explanation! Without a doubt it is valid.

Answer (score 12):

The method `OfType()` will skip the null values:

```
List<EmailParameterClass> parameterList =
    new List<EmailParameterClass>{param1, param2, param3...};

IList<EmailParameterClass> parameterList_notnull = 
    parameterList.OfType<EmailParameterClass>();
```

Comment: In a way, this is a good approach, but it brings a surprise to the developer who just thinks that `OfType` selects objects of a certain type, not thinking that it will not include `null` values ... So I'm a bit weary to introduce this into my own code.

Comment: @BjörnAliGöransson Agreed. It's an interesting solution, but it doesn't "read" very clearly. Using .RemoveAll with a lambda still keeps everything on a single line while making it really obvious as to what the developer who wrote it was trying to achieve. However, this might be useful if there's a speed benefit that's worthwhile.

Comment: The cool thing about this solution is, that it will change the generic parameter from T? to T.

Answer (score 12):

There is another simple and elegant option:

```
parameters.OfType<EmailParameterClass>();
```

This will remove all elements that are not of type `EmailParameterClass` which will obviously filter out any elements of type `null`.

Here's a test:

```
class Program
{
    class Test { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Test>();
        list.Add(null);
        Console.WriteLine(list.OfType<Test>().Count());// 0
        list.Add(new Test());
        Console.WriteLine(list.OfType<Test>().Count());// 1
        Test test = null;
        list.Add(test);
        Console.WriteLine(list.OfType<Test>().Count());// 1

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: will this work? won't be the element references still of type `EmailParameterClass` and only have a value equal to `null`?

Comment: It definitely will and i added tester for your entertainment.

Comment: This is great, especially when using nullable annotations because it not only filters out the nulls, but force-casts it to a non-nullable type (e.g. `Bitmap?[]`  becomes `Bitmap[]`)

Answer (score 4):

```
List<EmailParameterClass> parameterList = new List<EmailParameterClass>{param1, param2, param3...};

parameterList = parameterList.Where(param => param != null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy and without LINQ:

```
while (parameterList.Remove(null)) {};
```

Comment: That method is in `List` class just next to `RemoveAll`, so I'd recommend that one for clarity. If performance happened to be crucial, then you can go with this approach (although I'd remove the brackets and probably add a comment for unaware developers).

Comment: @Andrew: according to MSDN, RemoveAll does not take null. I think I also have tested that. A comment makes sense though.

Comment: `RemoveAll` received a `Predicate`, so you should use `RemoveAll(x => x == null)`, as seen in the accepted and Mark Bell's answer.