# How to exclude null rows during Json Deserialize?

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework

How can I exclude NULL entries from json. I de-serialize a string into a object list. I can access that null in that list but I want to exclude that null and stored not null rows into the list.

> [
>    {
>       "transactionId": 1778,
>       "locName": "IL",
>     },
>     {
>       "transactionId": 1779,
>       "locName": "NY",
>     },
>     {
>       "transactionId": 1774,
>       "locName": "IL",
>     },
>     {
>       "transactionId": 1771,
>       "locName": "NY"
>     },
>     **null**
>   ]

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TList>(inputText);
```

Comment: Have you thought about a `dynamic` object?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @FreekW. no, not want to use dynamic object

Comment: @sagi, I have edited my question and added the code.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9819797/5353753

Comment: Do you mean `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(inputText);`

Comment: @FreekW. yes, correct

Comment: @sagi, that for properties having null. I want something that exclude the full object row from the list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069748/how-to-remove-all-the-null-elements-inside-a-generic-list-in-one-go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you can't. Consider this code, which instructs JSON.NET to ignore null values:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var json = "[ { \"transactionId\": 1778, \"locName\": \"IL\", }, { \"transactionId\": 1779, \"locName\": \"NY\", }, { \"transactionId\": 1774, \"locName\": \"IL\", }, { \"transactionId\": 1771, \"locName\": \"NY\" }, null ]";

    var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
}

public class Entity
{
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string LocName { get; set; }
}
```

Then `list`'s last entry will still be `null`, because it's not a null *value*, it's a null *array element*.

If you wish to filter those, simply use Linq:

```
var nonNullList = list.Where(l => l != null).ToList();
```

Comment: I had to de-serialize first then exclude the nulls. Thanks