# How to ignore missing components in list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have camera script that moves camera with players. But when player is being destroyed by `Destroy(gameObject);` - camera stucks. It's because I have missing elements in list.

[image: missing elements]

***How to ignore this missing elements?***

or

***How to remove my destroyed target from list?***

But the second question is harder to explain.
I have script, in this script I imported list of targets. But this script doesn't work. It *doesn't remove* target from list.

```
    // PlayerController.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float hp1 = 7;
    public float damage2 = 4;
    private CamMove s1;


    void Start()
    {
        s1 = GetComponent<CamMove>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Bullet2")
        {
            hp1 -= damage2;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (hp1 <= 0) // death
        {
            s1.targets.Remove(GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1body").transform); // trying to remove target from list 
            Destroy(gameObject); // then desrtoy main object
        }
    } // also I added tag "Player1body" in Unity to my prefab
}
```

Comment: We need your Cam Move script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all the null elements inside a generic list in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069748/how-to-remove-all-the-null-elements-inside-a-generic-list-in-one-go) or wherever you iterate over the list simply do `if(element == null) continue;` if you want to keep the empty (`null`) entry in the list but skip it

Comment: `float GetGreatestDistance()
    {
        var bounds = new Bounds(targets[0].position, Vector3.zero);
        for (int i = 0; i < targets.Count; i++)
        {
            bounds.Encapsulate(targets[i].position);
        }

        return Mathf.Max(bounds.size.x, bounds.size.y);
    }`

Comment: some of cammove code

Comment: @derHugo where should I use it and what is `element`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line

```
s1.targets.Remove(GameObject.FindWithTag("Player1body").transform);
```

will allways remove the first encounter of objects with tag `"Player1body"` in the entire Scene - not specificly the one you actually wanted to remove (see [`GameObject.FindWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html)).

---

Checkout [How to remove all the null elements inside a generic list in one go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069748/how-to-remove-all-the-null-elements-inside-a-generic-list-in-one-go) to remove the empty (`null`) entries before going on

```
float GetGreatestDistance() 
{ 
    // removes all empty entries from the list
    targets.RemoveAll(item => item == null);

    // should check now if there is any entry available
    if(targets.Count == 0) return 0;

    var bounds = new Bounds(targets[0].position, Vector3.zero);

    for(var i = 1; i < targets.Count; i++) 
    { 
        bounds.Encapsulate(target.position); 
    } 

    return Mathf.Max(bounds.size.x, bounds.size.y); 
}
```

---

However if you want to keep the empty (`null`) elements in the list but skip them it gets only slightly more complicated:

```
float GetGreatestDistance() 
{ 
    // should check now if there is any entry available
    if(targets.Count == 0) return 0;

    Bounds bounds;

    // start loop at 0
    for(var i = 0; i < targets.Count; i++) 
    { 
        // skip if empty
        if(targets[i] == null) continue;

        // only for the first not empty entry do
        if(bounds == null)
        { 
            bounds = new Bounds(targets[i].position, Vector3.zero);
        }
        else
        {
            bounds.Encapsulate(target.position);
        } 
    } 

    // check if bounds was set
    return bounds == null ? 0 : Mathf.Max(bounds.size.x, bounds.size.y); 
}
```

Comment: Nice, great answer, but what is `item` in the second script? `targets.RemoveAll(item => item == null);`

Comment: This is a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). `item` is like the iterator in `foreach(var item in targets)`.

Comment: targets.RemoveAll(item => item == null); works great!